# Unable to connect to the oracle database due to IP change

Tags: java, database, jdbc, oracle11g, connection

I have set up `oracle11g` database on my system which is accessed by two other machines through `JDBC`. But due to some reason the `IP address` of my system has been changed. I am not able to access the database from other machines, even though I have changed IP address in `JDBC connection URL`,

But I am still getting `connection failure error` . `Network adapter could not establish the connection`

I have made changes in below code.

```
public static DbConnector getConnection(String dataSourceIp, String dataSourceJndiName) throws Exception {
        DbConnector con = new DbConnector();
        try {
            String jdbcURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.220.140.48:1521:test1";
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").newInstance();
            String user = "XXXX";
            String passwd = "YYYYYY";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, user, passwd);
            con.conn = conn;
            con.conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            return con;
            /*DataSource ds = getDataSource(dataSourceIp, dataSourceJndiName);
            con.conn = ds.getConnection();
            con.conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            return con;*/
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                // bu method getConnection methodudur. disconnectDB finally'ye
                // tasinmamalidir.
                String jdbcURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.220.140.48:1521:test1";
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").newInstance();
                String user = "xxxxx";
                String passwd = "yyyyyy";
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, user, passwd);
                con.conn = conn;
                con.conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                return con;
                /*dataSourceMap.remove(dataSourceIp + dataSourceJndiName);
                DataSource ds = getDataSource(dataSourceIp, dataSourceJndiName);
                con.conn = ds.getConnection();
                con.conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                return con;*/
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                con.disconnectDB();
            }
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

I have changed IP address in above code and replaced with new IP address.

Comment: Hi, could we see the actual error that you are getting (the JDBC Exception).

Comment: Can you access the database from your machine?  Have you activated a firewall on your machine?

Comment: Please write the Exception detail and the places where u have changed the IP Address

Comment: Reboot your system and try!

Comment: No this system is server we only access it from two other system

Comment: @PiyushBhardwaj, I usually use `netca` command of oracle to test whether this db can be accessed, if not solved, I reboot the server, my server is `windows`.

Comment: @JatinKhurana code is added.

Comment: @HiwayChe new IP address is Static IP rebooting does not solve the problem.

Comment: Try telnet command from other machine and on port 1521 and confirm whether you are able to connect or not.

Comment: @FireFly no Telnet end up with time out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install Oracle it install two more windows service.

1. `listener.ora`
2. `tnsnames.ora`

Change the IP in `tnsnames.ora` and `listener.ora` and restart your db.